# if statement is visible is undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get for id slide-1 that has an attr of displays block then add a class to id pagecount-1 of active. I'm trying to get for each slide the indicator shown to be active. This is what I have:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="sp active" id="slide-1" style="display: block"></div>
  <div class="sp" id="slide-2" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="sp" id="slide-3" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="sp" id="slide-4" style="display: none"></div>
</div>

<div id="page">
  <div id="page_count-1" class="indicate"></div>
  <div id="page_count-2" class="indicate"></div>
  <div id="page_count-3" class="indicate"></div>
  <div id="page_count-4" class="indicate"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    if ($('#slide-' + i).is(':visible')) {
        $('#page_count-' + i).addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Console log keeps displaying undefined. If I run `.attr('display', 'block')`
it makes all active.

Comment: `if(document.getElementById('slide-'+i).style.display === 'block') {`...

Comment: Why mix dom and jquery???

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tCQXw/

Comment: What console log are you talking about?

Comment: Looks like it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3GeRe/

Answer (score 1):

`display` is a CSS property, not an attribute. Try:

```
.css('display', 'block');
```

`.attr()` will set an attribute on the element, for instance:

```
<div id="some-div"></div>
```

Would turn into:

```
<div id="some-div" data-foobar="barfoo"></div>
```

If you run `.attr()` on it like this:

```
$("#some-div").attr("data-foobar", "barfoo");
```

Comment: .css ('display', 'block') this will work but just like the .attr once it runs it gives all active state:  <div class="page">
                
            <div id="page_count-1" class="indicate active">1</div><div id="page_count-2" class="indicate active">2</div><div id="page_count-3" class="indicate active">3</div><div id="page_count-4" class="indicate active">4</div>

Comment: @HRone I'm not sure what your issue is, the code you posted works on its own: http://jsfiddle.net/QQcnN/